# <a> doesn't work within a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button with three states (three different images) and it works and looks great except the primary function of a button - link to other document:)

When it's clicked, nothing happens. Do I need to use javascript or `<input>` or `<button>`?

I've tried it with `<button>` tag, but that three states didn't work.

And `<a id="backbutton">`... doesn't work either.

```
#backbutton{ width: 100px; height:100px; background-image: url('../obrazky/fs/back_up100.png'); }
#backbutton:hover{ background-image: url('../obrazky/fs/back_hover100.png'); }
#backbutton:active{ background-image: url('../obrazky/fs/back_down100.png'); }


<div id="backbutton"><a href="index.html"></a></div>
```

Comment: Linking to another document is _not_ the primary function of a button. Linking to another document is the primary function of a link.

Comment: Your anchor won't stretch to take up the entire div, so clicking on the background image isn't the same thing as actually clicking on the link. Also, you say you have a button, but that code just has `div` and `a` tags - no actual button.

Comment: And please never say "doesn't work"! Pet hate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
#backbutton a{display:block;width:100%;height:100%;}
```

to make the link inside the div to fit its container..

Answer (score 3):

The easiest (and *cleanest*) way is to not include that `div` there, just put `display: block;` on the link. That will make it become a block element, so, well, behave like a `div` would.

```
<a id="backbutton" href="index.html"></a>
```

And to the CSS:

```
#backbutton { display: block; width: 100px; height:100px; ... }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vvuzg/)

**And to answer your sidequestion**: for *linking to another document*, the right element to use is an `a` with its `href` attribute pointing to the other document. The `button` tag and the button variations of the `input` tag (`button`, `submit`, `reset`) are for defining *actions* that the user can take on the page (like submitting a form - which as a sideeffect might take you to a different page).

Comment: +1 for giving good context and to show proof of concept in the jsFiddle demo

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="backbutton"><a href="index.html"></a></div>
```

There is nothing to click on!  Try:

```
<div id="backbutton"><a href="index.html">Go home</a></div>
```

Or:

```
<a id="backbutton" href="index.html"></a>
```

And then add:

```
display:inline-block;
```

To the backbutton class.

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing inside the `a` tag. Stick in a `<span style="width:100%">` or something like that.

Edit: Gaby is right, [this isn't a portable solution](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width). Some other inline item, then. An invisible `img`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following CSS:

```
#backbutton a { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

The problem is that the `<a>` tag, which is the actual pushable link, doesn't have any content and therefore doesn't take up any space, so there's nowhere to click. I believe this CSS will expand it to the full size of the `div#backbutton`.